# How to disable docx table "Automatically resize to fit content"

Tags: apache-poi

Does anyone know how to disable the option "Automatically resize to fit content"?
I'm created a table 100% with 2 columns of 50% width each but when the text in the second column doesn't have any white spaces, like Chinese text it resizes the column. I'd like to disable it to have 2 equally sized columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
table.addNewTblLayout.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED)
```